# Bash autocompletion of script which is being sourced into the current shell

Tags: bash, shell, bash-completion

I have to change between lots of sub-directories within a set of a relatively few top-level directories. I want to make my life easier so I decided to look if I can script something. So I wrote this script `chdirp`:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "USAGE: chdirp direc"
   exit 1
fi
cd /some/top/level/directory/$1
```

Now, because of the whole sub-shell related thing, I am obligated to execute this script as follows for it to actually change the present working directory:

```
>>> . chdirp somewhere
```

All good so far. Now, i wanted to make my life a little more easier and make the script offer me tab-completions for possible sub-directories. So i found a complete script on the internet and got this:

```
_codeComplete() { 
   local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
   COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(/bin/ls /some/top/level/directory/)" -- $cur)) 
}
```

Then I assigned the completion function to my script. The problem is that although the tab completion works as expected when doing `>>> chdirp TAB` it does not work with `>>> . chdirp TAB`.

I would really like to combine the benefits of tab-completing the list of sub-directories and changing directoies quickly. Any advise how i can resolve my current problem?

Comment: Im not exactly sure, but have to tried setting an alias to run your script in same shell (using a   .   or source) and then see if auto completion works?.

Comment: Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/216803/bash-is-there-a-way-to-use-tab-completion-through-out-cdpath

Comment: Strange approach. Just create a symlink, and use the builtin autocompletion.

Comment: @ArunSangal Your suggestion does work! But lgfang's suggestion to put the functions in .bashrc seem like the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting your code into a stand alone script, I recommend you to put it into .bashrc as a function. This way, you needn't ". your_command xxx", you just "your_command xxx".

In addition, though it is not exactly an answer to your original question, I'd like to recommend a blog post from me. I think you are actually looking for an approach to bookmark a number of directories. I happen to have had done that to make my life easier. You may want to take a look at it at http://lgfang.github.io/images/bash-dir-bookmark.png Corresponding bash functions can be found at https://github.com/lgfang/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc

In fact, I did much more on changing between directories, making it really a snap. Please visit http://lgfang.github.io/computer/2015/12/18/bash-convenience for more details.

Comment: Your suggestion for putting the functions in `.bashrc` worked like a charm! i can easily combine it with my autocomplete functions now. Your bookmark routines looks quite cool too!